# SQL create policy for insert to check exist got passed to created

Tags: sql, postgresql, policy

I have a whitelist in which accounts are able to insert data into `promo`, I enable row level on my Postgres and create a policy like this:

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Role Api can create a promo of the user if exists on the whitelist."
       ON public.promo
       FOR INSERT TO role_api
       WITH CHECK (
        EXIST (SELECT pw.seller_id, pw.promo_type FROM public.promo_whitelist AS pw WHERE 
         (
           pw.seller_id = promo.seller_id AND pw.promo_type = promo.promo_type
         )
        )
       );
```

I also make grant all

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.promo TO role_api;
```

When I insert the data `seller_id` which is not in the whitelist, it passed; is something wrong with that query for checking?

Answer (score 0):

By default, policies are [permissive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html#id-1.9.3.75.6). If you have any other permissive policies on the table and you want this one to always be enforced, you need to make it restrictive. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/FFKTWzUL)

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Role Api can create a promo of the user if exists on the whitelist."
       ON public.promo
       AS RESTRICTIVE ------------here
       FOR INSERT TO role_api
       WITH CHECK (
        EXIST (SELECT FROM public.promo_whitelist AS pw 
               WHERE pw.seller_id = promo.seller_id 
               AND pw.promo_type = promo.promo_type )
       );
```

[From the doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html#id-1.9.3.75.6.4)

> there must be at least one `PERMISSIVE` policy granting access to the relation, and all of the `RESTRICTIVE` policies must pass

Which means that if you had any other permissive policy that matched, the query didn't have to match this one.

To test this operating as the table owner, you need to not just `enable` RLS, you need to [`force`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-DESC-FORCE-ROW-LEVEL-SECURITY) it to also apply to the table owner.

```sql
alter table public.promo enable row level security;
alter table public.promo force  row level security;
```

Make sure you're not testing this as a superuser or a [role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) with [`bypassrls` attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html) - as the names suggest, RLS doesn't apply to them.

You also don't need any columns after `select` in an `exists`: they all get discarded.

Comment: i tried RESTRICTIVE but doesnt work, but if you said it is not recommended for force row level ??

Comment: The only way a row can be inserted without passing the restrictive policy is if the inserting user is the owner of the table while RLS is only enabled, not forced, they are a `superuser` or have `bypassrls`. In psql client, you can see role attributes by typing `\du` and hitting enter or querying `select rolbypassrls,rolsuper from pg_catalog.pg_roles where rolname=current_user;`